# Swagger how to properly generate custom exception classes?

Tags: java, exception, swagger

I need to generate exception classes using swagger and Im not able to generate themm properly because my custom exception classes extends Exception, and Exception extends Throwable.

So when I say for exemple that the response is oneOf = {Ex1Error.class, 
Ex2Error.class} those classes extends Exception so the classes will generate missing somethings... is there a way to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for those with the same "problem", there is no way to do that yet.

As you can see here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/730

The comment from "wenyi189" describes exactly the same issue as me.
"It is 2019 now. And this is still not supported. I'm running into the exact problem where I have multiple sub types of APIException. And this APIException extends from RuntimeException from java. For example, if I have a subtype called UnexpectedException and it extends APIException, everything from parent class got picked up including the fields in Throwable.class. Very annoying and still couldn't find a way to get it working."

So yeah. No way to do that for now!

Answer (score 1):

Swagger by itself does not handle application exceptions as yet. You need to create an `ExceptionMapper` . Check this https://www.codepedia.org/ama/error-handling-in-rest-api-with-jersey/.
This solution its more elegant https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api. So either way, you need to create your own `class Mapper`

Comment: update: Already got the mapper, but well, I guess its impossible to generate the excep classes.
I will just put the code errors and desc with @ApiResponse
Any way to give some metadata about the exception class?